# Reference Request - Lagrange's Approach to Solve Polynomials by Radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, galois-theory

What is a decent reference that explains Lagrange's attempted approach to solve polynomials by radicals? It is not necessary, but it would be ideal, if it also compares this approach to Galois's approach.

Comment: See the references (and the references they cite) I gave in my answer to [History of the theory of equations: John Colson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493016/history-of-the-theory-of-equations-john-colson/497739#497739).

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chapter here, with a translated excerpt from Lagrange.

*Mathematical Expeditions
Chronicles by the Explorers*

Authors: Laubenbacher, Reinhard, Pengelley, David

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387984346

The authors' home page may have a version you can read free.